# gcovr doesn't recognise conditionals from Xcode 4.5

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, jenkins, code-coverage, cobertura

I have an Xcode 4.5 project for iOS 6.0 and I am trying to set up test coverage for Jenkins with Cobertura.

I have set up a test target and have configured both the main target and the test target correctly (Instrument Program Flow and Generate Test Coverage Files both on YES).

When the coverage report is generated (.gcda file), I translate it into XML using the gcovr tool ([version 2.4](https://software.sandia.gov/trac/fast/browser/gcovr/trunk/scripts)).

When I run the test on Jenkins, everything works fine and I can see the report through the Cobertura plugin. The only problem is that in the Cobertura report all the values for "Conditionals" are "N/A", while I see that there are conditionals (if-constructions) in the covered files.

My guess is that something happens in the translation to XML resulting in a faulty conversion of branches/conditionals, but I cannot find what it is.

The strange thing is that for some if constructions it does recognise the conditional. For example if I use the "STAssertEquals()" macro from the "SenTestingKit" library, the if constructions there are recognised.

I hope someone can help me with a fix for this problem or at least knows the cause. Please do not hesitate to ask me if you need more information.

Nicolas

Comment: Can you confirm that this is a gcovr error?  Does gcov capture the coverage of the conditionals?

Comment: Same issue here. I think I'm going to turn off conditionals within Jenkins for now.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. @user1161909 gcov captures branches in the program. Simple if conditions that put values in variables are not counted, but if you have something like: if(booleanValue) { [self method1] } else { [self method2] }, then it is counted